# How to load Windows 7 from GRUB rescue

Tags: grubrescue

1. I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed on the same partition
2. Some time later, decided to uninstall Ubuntu.So I booted Ubuntu,Changed the `hd` related to it to NTFS,I did NOT extended my main drive
3. restarted-> `GRUB rescue>`. No surprise since I had just wiped out the whole GRUB directory staff
4. Now I just want to boot into my windows.Move my necessary files to an external memory and reinstall the windows seven

What I have in my hands:
Ubuntu live CD, A copy of win7 DVD
I tried to make use of the win7 DVD(I had lost my DVD) to fix the mbr but the problem is when I choose repair, It says that this version of Windows is incompatible with yours
What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of doing that, is to download the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://ubcd.sourceforge.net/download.html), once downloaded, go ahead and burn the ISO to CD, boot from it, and run a command prompt.

Once you get the prompt, run the the following two commands in a command prompt:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Comment: Downloaded and wrote UBC, How can I get a command prompt?

Comment: I couldn't use UBCD.Thanks for the code.It worked.I'll update me post

Comment: This is still the best answer :D

Comment: If you don't have a Windows repair/recovery disc (which can be used to fix the bootloader), and don't have a copy of Ubuntu or some other Linux installed elsewhere (which can also be used to fix the bootloader), you may boot from a LiveCD of Ubuntu and [then move the bootloader to Windows](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1359802&p=10022261#post10022261):

    sudo apt-get install lilo
    sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr

To check which disk (e.g. `/dev/sda`) contains your Windows partition, use the _Disks_ application available on the LiveCD.

Comment: How do I run a commad prompt?

Comment: @Vader Go GRUB4DOS Menu, and then choose commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Using windows xp cd boot the machine, delete the linux partition and turn of the pc without installing windows xp operating system. 
Automatically system will boot normally. 
Reason: all the necessary files required by boot loader will be copied when you boot from cd.