# deleted ubuntu 14.04 partition error: unknown filesystem

Tags: grubrescue

By mistake I have deleted the Ubuntu 14.04 OS which is on dual boot with Windows 7.

After rebooting, following error message is displayed.

```
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode ..
grub rescue >
```

I tried to fix the issue by performing the following steps:

```
ls
set root=(hd0,msdos6)
set path=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
instmod normal
```

but nothing works.

Please let me know the steps for resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Re-install Ubuntu

- grub is failing because you deleted Ubuntu.
- re-installing Ubuntu will also re-install grub and then fix your problem

If, though, you want to use Windows and Windows solely on this machine you need to fix your Windows boot (ie. have Windows remove the grub references). See [How to load Windows 7 from GRUB rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316341/how-to-load-windows-7-from-grub-rescue)